# como descargar un archivo usando webbrowser?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, navegador-web

alguien podría orientarme con esto, quiero descargar un archivo de una pagina web sin mostrar  usando el control webbrowser, sin que se muestre cuadro de dialogo de descarga, que se descargue automáticamente. El elemento que quiero descargar tiene el siguiente código:

```html
<a class="accionicon" href="/Exito/DownloadRepresentacionImpresa?rfc=XXXXX000XX&amp;uuid=99094a5f-547a-474e-852d-5fe75f36e218" style="color:inherit;"><span title="Descargar representación impresa" class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span></a>
```

cabe mencionar que el url no es el mismo, se autogenera uno diferente en cada sesión dentro de la pagina

Comment: Te olvidaste de añadir el código a tu pregunta.

Comment: una disculpa, ya lo he añadido

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar el atributo download en la etiqueta <a>, seteando el nombre y extensión con una lógica del lado servidor o cliente:

```
<a class="accionicon" download="yourfile.jpg" href="/Exito/DownloadRepresentacionImpresa?rfc=XXXXX000XX&amp;uuid=99094a5f-547a-474e-852d-5fe75f36e218"   style="color:inherit;"><span title="Descargar representación impresa" class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>EEE</a>
```

En este [enlace](https://caniuse.com/#search=download) puedes validar cuáles navegadores soportan este atributo.